iOS 17.x <OPTGROUP> no longer visible?
I have a web-app that uses an <OPTGROUP> within a <SELECT> and everything worked fine until I upgraded to iOS 17.x and now the the <OPTGROUP> value is not visible in (Safari/Chrome/Firefox) and it renders a grey line where that value should be.  Everything is fine on Android and a computer browser.
Does anyone know how to resolve?



Sorry for the obvious question, but have you made certain it's not a different bug? E.g. Are the elements actually being output from the server to the browser? Is it rendering correctly in different versions of iOS and desktop browsers? Is it a stylesheet issue (try using the desktop browser to emulate a phone screen)? Adding screenshots from desktop, iOS 17, and iOS 16 would help us diagnose.

I don't believe its a different bug, let me clarify though that this is only mobile...yes, the elements are being properly output. yes, it renders properly in iOS 16.x mobile but not 17.x. mobile and properly in other browsers other than 17.x.  Properly when emulated on a desktop too in Developer mode both Windows and Mac
